# VS Android Emulator in reboot loop on Windows 10 (Hyper-V) in Hyper-V 2016

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

**Environment**

1. Hyper-V server 2016 Technical Preview 4
2. Virtual machine running Windows 10 and nested vm's enabled (I can run Windows Phone emulators)

*Note that I am running hyper-v (emulator on windows 10) inside a hyper-v server, but that is supported with the builds I have.*

**Problem description**

I can create and start the vm, but after 3 seconds and this screen, the machine resets itself. I was able to grab a screenshot by pausing the virtual machine:

[image]

When I check out the log of the `Visual Studio Emulator for Android manager`, this is what I see:

```
3> 4-12-2015 21:58:18 : [Critical] Could not launch 'VS Emulator 5" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone' device. Exit code -532462766.
3> 4-12-2015 21:58:18 : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
3> 4-12-2015 21:58:18 : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\Geert\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_Lollipop_(5.0)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone.geert"
3> 4-12-2015 21:58:18 : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: Unknown (-532462766)
```

When I check the `event log`, I see this:

```
Application: xde.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Communication.XdePeerGuest.DetectGuest()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**What I did in order to try and fix it (but failed)**

1. Delete and re-install the virtual machines
2. Delete and re-install the emulator images using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android
3. Delete and re-install the network switches of the inner-hyper-v

Comment: -532462766 = 0xE0434352 = CLR expcetion and in the log you see that a System.ObjectDisposedException occured. Submit the issue to Microsoft on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ For me the emulator stucks in "starting OS" and nothing happens. It is buggy as hell.

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2095819/android-emulator-keeps-rebooting-in-hyper-v-nested-virtualization

Comment: you should use **procdump -ma -i C:\dumps** to generate a dump of XDE.exe. zip and attach the dmp to connect

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit too far out on the bleeding edge for this to work. The VS Emulator for Android hasn't been tested in nested Hyper-V because nested Hyper-V is still under development. Unfortunately, I don't think that this will be fixed until nested Hyper-V is closer to RTM.